# (Roblox) Remoteevents teleporting

Tags: roblox

serverscriptservice script

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.AdminEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,action,arg1,arg2)
        if action == "Teleport" then
        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = arg1.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
        print(arg1)
        print(arg1.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame)
        print(plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame)
```

local gui button script

```
    
    
function OnClicked() 
    print("clicked")
    
    local arg1

    for index, v in pairs(game.Players:GetDescendants()) do if v:Is(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.TextLabel.Text) then arg1 = v
            local action = "Teleport"
            local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
        
        

    game.ReplicatedStorage.AdminEvent:FireServer(plr,action,arg1)
            end
    script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(OnClicked)
        
    end 
end

    
    game.ReplicatedStorage.AdminEvent:FireServer(plr, action, arg1)
```

no errors in output or the stuff that I try printing like the CFrame

Answer (score 0):

idk why i got logged in  a different account when pressing login with google but I solved this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are passing 3 args `plr,action,arg1` and receiving 4 args.
If you receive more args than what is passed then the first arg defaults to the player.
Also I never recommend passing the player value as it could be exploited.

Here is the fix:

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.AdminEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,action,arg1)
        if action == "Teleport" then
           plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = arg1.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
           print(arg1)
           print(arg1.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame)
           print(plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame)
        end
end)
```

```lua
    
    
function OnClicked(PlayerWhoClicked) 
    print("clicked")
    local arg1
    for index, v in pairs(game.Players:GetDescendants()) do
       if v:Is(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.TextLabel.Text) then
            arg1 = v
            local action = "Teleport"
            game.ReplicatedStorage.AdminEvent:FireServer(action,arg1)
       end

    end 
end
---I don't know why this was in the loop, but it shouldn't be.
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(OnClicked)
```

Before, you would be receiving 2 player args, so this should fix it and that's why it wasn't erroring.

Now, you can use two player arguments if you're doing admin commands, but make sure to check the first one to be an admin and do not pass it, let the arg default to it.